# Чтение данных из файла JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, файлы

У меня есть файл JSON. Я знаю **key**, с помощью которого могу достать **value** этого ключа. Но беда в том, что я не понимаю как мне обратиться к этому файлу, чтобы достать из него значение какого-либо ключа JSON. Пишу на C# .NET Framework 4.8

Искал в интернете информацию, но так и не смог понять как это сделать.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Comment: Framework 4.x устарел. Но если по каким-то непреодолимым причинам вы не можете использовать современный .NET, то вас спасет библиотека Newtonsoft.Json. Примеров работы с ней полинтернета.

Comment: Да хоть .net 1.0, только с такими вопросами нужно пример файла json.

Comment: В .NET FW есть встроенные средства для работы с JSON: [JavaScriptSerializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8), [DataContractJsonSerializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Как сразу из файла  key или value достать - не заню.
Но можно декомпозировать задачу:

1. Сначала выясни как читать из файла текст любой. К примеру StreamReader.
2. А потом уже разбирайся как парсить этот JSON текст ( к примеру библиотека newtonsoft.json или другие)